# Client certificate in Window phone 8

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8

We are at present working on porting iOS and Android application to Windows phone 8. We are facing a major road block. Both of these platforms supports SSL (i.e. client certificate in HTTPRequest that are not installed in Windows phone My Store). I have seen these links also

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/49384ad1-a1ff-4ec8-8d8d-f01a3f602e88/phone-8-client-ssl-authentication?forum=wpdevelop

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5e0b194f-6a83-4998-bf6c-534012195107/how-to-handle-client-certificates-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop

From these links I understand that MS does not support client certificate in windows phone 8 for security (???) reasons.

So are there any work around to this problem. Are there any 3rd party free/paid libraries that can solve this problem for me? When you suggest some such source, please can you also point me to a working example using that library.

**Please do not mark this as duplicate as None of the other post in Stackoverflow or MSDN forums talks about the possible work around with code sample.**

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks and regards

**Update 1**

I did some further research. They are as follows

I made an analysis by using the Bouncy castle. My analysis shows that the following are  the call that is happening between the client and the server.

1. type :server_hello
2. type :certificate (Server sent certificate being validated)
3. type :server_hello_done
4. type :finished

Actually there are many other intermediate steps that needs to happen regarding the SSL Handshake. As  per this link  >http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc%2Fsy10660_.htm
the intermediate steps of asking for the client certificate is not happening. Are there any other folks who are sailing like the same boat as mine.
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no workaround. Install client certificate by hand or do not port the application to windows phone.

Comment: Potentially you can use our SecureBlackbox - it has its own certificate handling AND HTTPS client component (HTTPRequest or anything else is not used).

Comment: Hi Eugene, Can you please share some links that provides architecture, code sample of this component.

Comment: Is it possible to use   var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
   filter.ClientCertificate = ...

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by @totfum in the comments works in 8.1:

> Is it possible to use:
>
> ```
> var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter(); 
> filter.ClientCertificate =
> ```